# how can i remove object from Tweenlite

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, papervision3d, gsap

how can i remove object from Tweenlite

```
        private var planeCards:Plane;
        protected function animate():void
        {

            for (var i:int = 0; i <planes.length; i++)
            {
                planeCards = planes[i];
                //Each if statement will adjust these numbers as needed
                var planeX:Number = 0;
                var planeZ:Number = -50;
                var planeRotationY:Number = 0
                if (i == currentItem)
                {
                    planeZ   = -300
                    TweenLite.to(planeCards, 1, { rotationY:planeRotationY,x:planeX,z:planeZ, ease:Quint.easeInOut } );
                }
                //Place & Animate Right Items
                if(i> currentItem)
                {
                    planeX   = (i - currentItem + 1) * 120;
                    planeRotationY   = angle + 10 * (i - currentItem);
                    TweenLite.to(planeCards, 1, { rotationY:planeRotationY,x:planeX,z:planeZ, ease:Quint.easeInOut } );
                }
                //Place & Animate Left Items
                if (i <currentItem)
                {
                    planeX   = (currentItem - i + 1) * -120;
                    planeRotationY   = -angle - 10 * (currentItem - i);
                    TweenLite.to(planeCards, 1, { rotationY:planeRotationY,x:planeX,z:planeZ, ease:Quint.easeInOut } );
                }
            }
        }
```

I want remove "planeCards" from Tweenlite because if i am loading different images in "planes.length" in run time  means previous images will not hide. It display behind the new images, how can clear old "planeCards"
want can i do.........pls help me

Comment: What are 'planeCards'? How are you adding them?

Comment: private var planeCards:Plane; I have already apply bitmapFileMatrial and  stored in ArrayCollection planes.

Comment: how can i remove a object from TweenLite

Answer (score 2):

1) You can call [TweenLite.killTweensOf](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/TweenLite.html#killTweensOf%28%29), that will stop all the tweens for specified target.

2) You can use different approach. If you have a couple of tweens and need to manage them alltogether, consider using nonstatic way. Create tween via new, store somewhere, retrieve and stop if needed:

```
var tween:TweenLite = new TweenLite(planeCards, 1,
    { rotationY:planeRotationY,x:planeX,z:planeZ, ease:Quint.easeInOut } );
tween.play();

// ...

tween.kill();
```